# Compilation exited abnormally with code 2

Tags: c, unix, emacs, compilation

I am using Unix environment in emacs for the first time. I wrote a c program and then did `M-x compile` and enter. Then I was asked for compile command. The default command was some `make -k` and I did hit enter but it stopped abnormally with the message. Then I did `gcc hello_world.c` and then it did the same. I am befuddled at this point. Any help is appreciated. Note: I have never used emacs or Unix before and has some basic command line knowledge of Unix so I implore that you explain your answer so that I and others who are new can understand.

**Add-on:** Just tried `clang` and it now exits with code 127. No idea whatsoever on how to advance forward.

**Edit:**

My step by step process for others to better understand my problem:

1. `emacs hello_world.c`
2. wrote the `hello_world.c` program.
3. `M-x compile`
4. Compile command: `gcc hello_world.c`

saved. And then no file or directory (although I do have a file and directory, I can see that  I can see that in my moba-xtreme GUI interface). No input files. And then abnormal termination.
.

Comment: I recommend you do the exercises from here: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ which will show you how to build from the command-line step-by-step.

Comment: can use post the compilation error message given by `gcc hello_world.c`

Comment: @sps compilation exited abnormally with code 1. No input files

Comment: can you edit you post, and paste the exact error messge? Its unclear what you are saying.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood what I asked earlier. I asked you to paste the error message, not the steps.  Did you try compiling from the command line (shell)? In shell, go to the directory where you have your file and try `gcc hello_world.c` in your shell prompt. Do you get same error?

Comment: @LouFranco Reading the book you recommended, I have no words on how to show my gratitude.You showed me the right path.